# How use SQL CASE & COUNT in JOIN Table

Tags: mysql, sql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fb5nS.png)I want to summarize the student's clearance status into a single result using join query. tbl_student and tbl_trns_clr
example if all office status is Cleared then remarks is Cleared 
else if one office is not cleared then remark is Not Cleared

[image]

```
SELECT *
FROM `tbl_student` as A join
     `tbl_trns_clr` as B 
     on B.EDP = A.EDP AND
        CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*)
                   FROM tbl_trns_clr
                   WHERE B.clr_status = 'Not Cleared' AND A.EDP = B.EDP
                  ) = 0 THEN 'Cleared'
         END) as clr_status
```

and I wanna make it appear like the Table UI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to just want a scalar expression in the `SELECT`, not an explicit `JOIN`:

```
SELECT s.*,
       (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                          FROM tbl_trns_clr c
                          WHERE c.clr_status = 'Not Cleared' AND
                                c.EDP = s.EDP
                         )
             THEN 'Cleared' ELSE 'Not Cleared'
         END) as clr_status
FROM `tbl_student` s;
```

Notes:

- Use table aliases that are *meaningful*.  Random letters like `A` and `B` just make the query hard to follow.
- You don't need to use `COUNT(*)`.  `NOT EXISTS` is more appropriate and has better performance -- because it can stop at the first value that matches.

Comment: Is there a performance difference between writing `Select 1` and `Select *` ? if I were to write a query plan, I would see that the results are only used in an exists clause and optimise it internally.

Comment: *"Is there a difference between writing Select 1 and Select * "*  No it does not matter in MySQL/mariaDB atleast @UniqIdentifierAssignedAtBirth as you can even write NULL. 1/0 there as the optimizer knows it need to run `NOT EXISTS` in "boolean mode" and "ignores" what is after the SELECT... The `Select 1` is the best way to maintain support for other databases